# jQuery - How to dynamically hide submit button when you delete e-mail at input field?

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, input

Notice it when you type a valid e-mail... then delete this email and it doesn't hide submit button. There a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BGNsS/

Can anyone help me?

thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for a valid regex and the length. Your regex has success for a empty field.

You check the length of the collection of jQuery elements here

```
if(!$("#sForm input#write").length > 0) $("input#sub").hide();
```

But you must check the length of the value

```
detectEmail.length == 0
```

#### [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGNsS/17/)

```
$('input#sub').hide();

$('input').keyup(function() {
    $('span.attention').hide();

    var detectEmail = $(this).val();
    var emailRegex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    if(detectEmail.length == 0 || !emailRegex.test(detectEmail)) 
    {
        $('#sub').hide();
        $(this).after('<span class="attention">Writing valid e-mail...</span>');
    }
    else 
    {
        $('#sub').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: `if ( detectEmail.length == 0 || !emailRegex.test(detectEmail) )` - checking first the length will avoid executing the regex for nothing I guess.

Comment: @DidierGhys good idea, i update my answer. Do you understand why someone downvotet my answer ?

Comment: Awesome, i didn't know very well about ==, so it worked as charm, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The check for empty string is actually wrong.

This one returns the number of elements (which is always 1):

```
$("#sForm input#write").length
```

Change to something like this

```
$("#sForm input#write").val().length
```